# Why does MySqlParameter Add parameter as 0 convert to null

Tags: c#, mysql, null, mysql-parameter

I'm adding a parameter to be called with a MySQL stored procedure like

```
List<MySqlParameter> MyParams = new List<MySqlParameter>();    
MyParams.Add(new MySqlParameter("MyId", 0));
```

But for some reason when I look at MyParams, MyId value when stepping through my code, it is converted to null.  Does anyone know why this is because if I assign the value from a int variable like below it is fine

```
int id = 0;
List<MySqlParameter> MyParams = new List<MySqlParameter>(); 
MyParams.Add(new MySqlParameter("MyId", id));
```

Comment: Post the code for `MySqlParameter`, without it this question is unanswerable.

Comment: MySqlParameter is part of the MySql .Net API :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html

Comment: OK, that My* stuff. The we still need to see how MyParams gets pushed to the Command.

Comment: @downvoter Can you give a reason for `down-voting` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, You fell into the corner case of c# that literal `0` can be converted to `Enum` *implicitly*

> An implicit enumeration conversion permits the decimal-integer-literal 0 to be converted to any enum-type

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691283%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

So, `new MySqlParameter("MyId", 0)` is compiled into `MySqlParameter(string,MySqlDbType)` rather than `MySqlParameter(string,object)` as the result your value `0` is ignored.

`new MySqlParameter("MyId", id)` this works because implicit conversions to enum works only when the value is `literal` not for `variables`. So It is clear that this gets compiled into `MySqlParameter(string,object)` resulting the expected results.

```
new MySqlParameter("MyId", (object)0)//this solves the problem
```

or this

```
New MySqlParameter("MyId", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = 0
```

BTW as @Suraj Singh pointed you may have to use `@MyId` instead of `MyId`.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Use caution when you use this overload of the `SqlParameter` constructor to specify integer parameter values. Because this overload takes a value of type Object, you must convert the integral value to an Object type when the value is zero ---[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
Hope it's applicable for `MySql` too.

```
MyParams.Add(New MySqlParameter("@MyId", MySqlDbType.int)).Value = 0;
```

or try

```
Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyId", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your database schema, Is MyId a Primary Key of type int? with allow null set to yes?

assigning a value of 0 to a PK with allow null, will result in NULL being assigned.
I suspect its the database setup and not the code at fault.

Comment: MyId is part of a PrimaryKey of type INT.  In the table schema the column is set to NOT NULL

Comment: But `0` is not `null`.

Comment: ^agree. Why would you want to insert 0 as a PK? what happens when you insert '1' instead?

Comment: @AaronHopkins MyId is PART of a PrimaryKey, not a single column primary key

Comment: Your database, your rules. No worries.